# managing argparse with multiple files

Tags: python, import, python-import, argparse

I have a parser in mainParser.py

This parser is very basic and just has the -h and -v options.

However, it also has **`subparsers`**.

Each subparser is in a different file `sub_1.py, sub_2.py` etc`.

All the (sub)parsers functions are in `parserFunctions.py`

Here is the hierarchy:

```
Parsers /
    ParserPackage /
        - __init__.py
        - mainParser.py
        - sub_1.py
        - sub_2.py
        - parserFunctions.py
```

**mainParser.py:**

```
import argparse
from Parsers.ParserPackage.parserFunctions import mainParserFunc

mainParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    prog="XXX",
    description="YYY",
    add_help=False
)

SUBPARSER = mainParser.add_subparsers(title="ZZZ")

mainParser.add_argument(...)
    .
    .
    .
mainParser.set_defaults(func=mainParserFunc)
```

**sub_1.py**

```
from Parsers.ParserPackage.parserFunctions import sub_1_parserFunc
from Parsers.ParserPackage.mainParser import SUBPARSER

sub_1_parser = SUBPARSER.add_parser(name="AAA")
sub_1_parser.add_argument(...)
    .
    .
    .
sub_1_parser.set_defaults(func=sub_1_parser_parserFunc)
```

**sub_2.py**

```
from Parsers.ParserPackage.parserFunctions import sub_2_parserFunc
from Parsers.ParserPackage.mainParser import SUBPARSER

sub_2_parser = SUBPARSER.add_parser(name="BBB")
sub_2_parser.add_argument(...)
    .
    .
    .
sub_2_parser.set_defaults(func=sub_2_parser_parserFunc)
```

## THE ISSUE:

when I call `mainParser.parse_args(myArgs.split())`:
it says `invalide choice 'AAA'/'BBB' (choose from ).

why?

Comment: Show a sample `myArgs` and full error.  The '-h' help might also help.

Comment: @hpaulj the full error is as I wrote.
Regarding the -h, it doesn't display the subparsers

Answer (score 0):

After multiple tries, I've found the solution.

Since the mainParser didn't import the subparsers (obviously), it didn't know about their existence.

The proper solution is to have a new file that will import the mainParser but also all the subparsers.
When the import occurs - it lad the code and then define the mainParser properly